# I want to make a an API request from Xencall CRM to Zillow and it is giving me error "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, zillow

I am getting XML response from the Zillow API so I don't want any answers for JSON responses. 
I want to make an API request from Xencall CRM to Zillow and it is giving me error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=XXXXX...from origin 'https://XX.xencall.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
I just want to know how to add this Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in my request. Here is my code:

```
<p>Click the button to view the Zillow details of the Address</p>
<button onclick="userAction()" type="submit">Find from Zilow</button>

<p id="beds">&nbsp;</p>

<script> 
    function userAction() {
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        const url='https://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-ZXXXXXXXXX&address=(Profile.Address)&citystatezip=(Profile.City) (Profile.State) (Profile.Zip Code)&rentzestimate=true';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();

        Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            var res=Http.responseText;
            var bed1=res.split('<bedrooms>')[1];
            var bed= bed1.split('</bedrooms>')[0]; 
            var bath1=res.split('<bathrooms>')[1];
            var bath= bath1.split('</bathrooms>')[0];  
            var zest1=res.split('<zestimate>')[1];  
            var zest= zest1.split('</amount>')[0];  
            var zest_rep=zest.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,'');
            var zest_40=zest_rep*0.42; 
            var zest_60=zest_rep*0.62;
            var final_html="Bedrooms: "+bed+"<br/>"+"Bathrooms: "+bath+"<br/>"+"Zestimate: "+zest+"<br/>"+"Zestimate Low Range: "+zest_40.toFixed(2)+"<br/>"+"Zestimate High Range: "+zest_60.toFixed(2); 

           document.getElementById("beds").innerHTML =final_html;
       }
   };
</script>
```

Comment: that site doesn't allow cross origin requests *I just want to know how to add this Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in my request* - no ... it's a **response** header - you can't tell a site to let you in

Comment: @Bravo But when I am disabling the CORS by making a shortut icon using the command for Windows 10: On Windows 10 command will be: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
This command will disable security feature from Chrome and its working. I don't think then that it is from Zillow server side. Is it?

Comment: if you disable security then a) of course CORS won't be blocked, because you've told your browser to ignore CORS security measures; and b) you will be exposing your browser to the internet, with no security measures in place - good luck with that - you really need to understand the purpose of CORS .... it stops malicious web activity not only from YOUR page, but from other pages

Answer (score 1):

Zillow is not allowing your domain to make requests to its API.

This is a safety measure Zillow has taken. If your domain should be allowed to make API requests to Zillow (if you have a developer relationship with them), then you should contact Zillow and ask them to whitelist your domain.

For more reading on the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` **response** header please read the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: But when I am making the same request from my CORS disabled version of Google Chrome by using the command: On Windows 10 command will be: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
Then it is giving the response. Is it really from server side or do I need to change something in my request?